# Service which allows me to use a VM for accessing Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, virtual-machine

Is there a service available where I can access Visual Studio to write .NET programs? This way I won't have to install Visual Studio on my machine, and I can access it on different laptops.

Similar to how you can create a virtual machine for Ubuntu, CentOS and other operating systems with a MEAN stack set up or a Node.js setup.

Also with this service, if I pay its monthly subscription, I wouldn't have to buy Visual Studio outright.

Comment: You can install virtualization software, grab a Windows ISO and get to work. No external services needed :)

Comment: Oh, I see here that you don't want to use a local VM...

Comment: Unless you are an "enterprise", Visual Studio Community Edition is free and has everything you need.  This is in response to "wouldn't have to buy".. not the initial question.

Comment: grooveplex has the right idea here even if it wasn't what you asked for specifically.  Windows has awesome remote desktop capabilities.  IF you ran a VM under linux (or just a separate windows box).. you can use RemoteDesktop (or even VNC) to access it from anywhere to include other linux machines.
There is also monodevelop.
https://www.monodevelop.com/

Comment: There's no such service, unfortunately. Your best option, as suggested by others, is to run it through a VM

Answer (score 3):

You could use an Azure cloud VM, and install visual studio community (or another free version) on it.

This would give you a desktop Windows machine in the cloud. It could be a little pricey though. If you join the Microsft MPN, you can get some free Azure time.

Personally, I would just get one of the free versions of Visual Studio and run it locally on the various machines.

Comment: when you say run it locally you mean within the same building i am in?

Comment: Em yes, although you could use a VPN and get remote access that way, either on an actual machine or using virtualbox. As others have mentioned above, there are free fully functional editions of visual studio available - these can be used even on multiple machines. It would be simpler and faster to just install wherever you want it